# 'SalesforceBulk' object has no attribute 'post_bulk_batch'

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, salesforce, bulk

I'm trying to run a bulk job in salesforce. After creating job and prepared csv_iterator through my data, when i ran this

```
batch = bulk.post_bulk_batch(job, csv_iterator)
```

I'm getting the error stating

```
AttributeError: 'SalesforceBulk' object has no attribute 'post_bulk_batch'
```

I've installed salesforce_bulk in python2 and 3 as well. Tried in both versions, but same error.
Why is this happens. How to rectify this issue? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I have installed the version **salesforce-bulk==1.1.0** 
Now it is **working in python2** but in **python3** this is what happening

```
from salesforce_bulk import SalesforceBulk
ImportError: cannot import name 'SalesforceBulk'
```

Is there no support for python 3 to do salesforce bulk job process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! In python3 install version salesforce-bulk == 2.1.0 and change the method name **post_bulk_batch** to **post_batch** 
That's it do the trick!

Comment: Actually the method nothing related with the python version. It all depends on the salesforce_bulk version what you have installed.